# Improper Integral in four dimensions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Considering the integral

$I = \prod_{i=1}^4 (\int_\infty^\infty dk_i sinc (k_ia_i + b_i)sinc (k_iA_i + B_i) )\frac {k_1^n}{k_1^2+k_2^2+k_3^2+k_4^2}$

with parameters $n,a,b,A,B$ I tried to use contour integration. But now I stuck here. How can I solve this integral?

Comment: interesting mathematica really hates this integrals, even in the single variable case